# how to add style to specific input type=text

Tags: html, css

In my login page I have 3 input type=text elements.Now I want to apply style to one specific element.Like I want to apply style for the following element only...

```
<input type="text" value="enter username or email or mobile number" id="username" name="username" />
```

when I am using css

```
input[type=text]
```

then that style is applying on all the three elements.i don't want that.I want to apply style on only one specific element.How to achieve this...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tags ID for more precision...

```
input#username[type=text]
```

... obviously also means you can just leave away the type filter...

```
input#username
```

... since there can only be one element with that id.

Apart from that you could also use other properties for filtering, for example the name:

```
input[type=text][name="username"]
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can used selector properties for this 
for example you can try id selector like this

```
<input type="text" value="enter username or email or mobile number" id="username" name="username" />

    <style>
        #username{
            color:red;
            font-size:20px;
        }
    </style>
```

and your other control will not effect.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way is just to do this:

```
<input style="color:red" type="text" value="enter username or email or mobile number" id="username" name="username" />
```